# starting second container on same data-volume doesnt work

Tags: docker

I am trying to run two instances of couchdb sharing the same data-volume container.

I created the container using the below command

```
docker create -v /opt/couchdb/data --name couchdb-data debian:jessie /bin/true
```

And then started to containers on the same volume.

```
docker run -d -p 5984:5984 -v /opt/couchdb/data --name couchdb-1 --volumes-from couchdb-data klaemo/couchdb
docker run -d -p 5985:5984 -v /opt/couchdb/data --name couchdb-2 --volumes-from couchdb-data klaemo/couchdb
```

I put data in one and try to access from the other.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value":"ORielly"}' http://172.17.0.2:5984/db 
{"ok":true,"id":"9071064ff053a75d3c639fbf8d00098c","rev":"1-8b72db504e321c6d49070196dc426a19"}
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value2":"ORielly"}' http://172.17.0.2:5985/db
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 5985: Connection refused
```

The second one gives connection refused - not sure what the reason is.

**UPDATE**

It looks like I was using the container IP with the wrong port to access the data.
However, It looks like sharing the data volume in couch db doesn't seem to share with already running containers. It does get get shared if you start a new container with the same data volume

Comment: What does `docker ps` show?

Comment: docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED               STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
    4cfe49a7be57        klaemo/couchdb      "tini -- /docker-e..."   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5985->5984/tcp   couchdb-2
    f793b380d8dc        klaemo/couchdb      "tini -- /docker-e..."   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp   couchdb-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `-p 5985:5984` means: HostPort=>5985, ContainerPort=>5984.
If you access to the container IP directly, so you need to use  the ContainerPort. Otherwise curl to `localhost:5985`.

Also, this `172.17.0.2` is the IP of one container, you are using it for both.

This will let you know each container IP:

```
docker inspect couchdb-1 -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge.IPAddress}}'

docker inspect couchdb-2 -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge.IPAddress}}'
```

Comment: I inspected the ip adress of both containers they are 172.17.0.2 and 172.17.0.3 respectively. I am able to hit the container using 02 address but the 03 says refuses connection.  
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value3":"ORielly"}' http://172.17.0.3:5985/db
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3 port 5985: Connection refused. 
Your suggestion on using localhost seems to be working but I dont see why it should work for 02:5984 and not for 03:5985. Also, since they share the same data volume I should be able to access inserted by one on the other.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it there are all the ports that the container data is accessible:
"http://localhost:5985/db/_all_docs"
"http://localhost:5984/db/_all_docs"
"http://172.17.0.3:5984/db/_all_docs"
"http://172.17.0.2:5984/db/_all_docs"

Comment: Although I am able to access correctly. It looks like sharing the data volume doesnt share the data...

Comment: Your volumes configuration looks good. Are you sure that the data is not shared?

Comment: It looks like sharing the data volume in couch db doesn't seem to share with already running containers. It does get get shared if you start a new container with the same data volume